# Windows command line gulp error Code 800A03EE Microsoft JScript Compilation Error

Tags: cmd, .net-core, visual-studio-code, gulp

I am building a .NET Core 2.2 project with a framework (Syncfusion) and I am using Visual Studio Code and the windows cmd tool for setting up the environment. On running 'gulp copy' I am getting this error:

Line: 2
Char: 29
Error: Expected ')'
Code: 800A03EE
Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error.

Interestingly running 'gulp -v' to check the installation results in the same error.

This is the code of my gulp.js file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
    gulp.task('copy', async function () { 
        gulp.src('./node_modules/syncfusion-javascript/**') 
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib/syncfusion-javascript')); 
    });
```

I can't understand why there is an error with the brackets as to me there are equal numbers of brackets and curly brackets.

Thanks very much!

Comment: JScript doesn't seem to know about async functions, so it thinks `async` is a variable name. But I suspect the real problem is that JScript is involved at all.

Comment: Removing Async just gives me another Microsoft JScript compilation error. It's not just the Async keyword it doesn't recognise. What could be causing the problem? My environment seems to be properly set up?